# Can I specify a set of base parameters for a Linq-to-sql DataContext?

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have a LINQ-to-SQL DataContext that represents a parent-child relationship of Products to Prices. I'm iterating through a list of products and retrieving the prices for each one.  The problem is that the tables behind both the Products and Prices contain a list of Products or Prices for multiple environments, determined by a 3 field complex key.  I want to retrieve the Products and Prices for only one of those environments.

I can do this be specifying a long where clause in each LINQ query consisting of the product key and the complex environment key, something like this:

```
var price = ( from condition in conditiontype where condition.MaterialNumber == material && condition.Client == "400" && condition.SalesOrg == "1000" && condition.DistributionChannel == "10" select condition.ConditionDetails[0].ConditionValue );
```

what I'd like to be able to do is to specify the Client, SalesOrg, and DistributionChannel globally for the DataContext so that all I need to specify in the query itself is the Product ID (MaterialNumber).  That way when I starting querying our Production environment a simple change to the DataContext will change what environment I'm querying.

Is this possible?  Either a brief code sample or pointers to the background theory would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a pre-written `Expression<T>` which you then have those values in it:

```
public Expression<Func<int>> GetPrices = p => // do Lambda here
```

Alternatively you can put properties into your DataContext (remember, it's a **partial** class so it's easy to extend) which you set and are then read in by your expression.

Comment: That was my thinking, but I'm not sure where to set those values within the partial class.

Comment: you should create a separate code file for your bits. Keep in mind that the .designer files are auto generated so you should never edit them!